# filtering special chars from post slug

Tags: permalinks, slug

Is there a way to prevent WordPress from including special characters like – (long dash), ", ', etc.. from the post slugs?

Basically, I'd like to run the post-slug through a filter when it is created, and strip any special chars.

The reason is, that it's giving me problems as these show up as utf8-urlencoded in my rss feed, and those links don't work.

Comment: allowed tags, etc. can be found in formatting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for:

```
<?php

    // Cleans special characters out of the slug, if the slug hasn't been set yet
    add_filter('name_save_pre', 'clean_slugs', 0);

?>
```

Comment: Just a reminder, when you are back, don't forget to mark this as your answer. :)